# C++ libraries for working with MySql

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm searching for a good C++ library for MySql, I read about MySQL++ and SQLAPI++, from your experience witch one should I use from this two or is there another library that you would recomand ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple more to consider are [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) and [DTL](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/). Most of the general purpose frameworks like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com), [Ultimate++](http://www.ultimatepp.org/), and [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) include database access capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql now distributes an official C++ library based on JDBC.  I would use that unless there is some compelling reason not to(note there are plenty of those DB portability, licensing. )